# Variable scope is not available in inner cursor in query

Tags: oracle, scope, cursor

In below query i can not use c.college_id in inner most query as it is out out scope but is there any solution that i could use c.college_id value in inner most query and i dont want to call 'coll_details' with-query inside as it will impact the performance.

```
WITH  coll_details AS (SELECT   cd.college_id
                        ,   cd.college_name
                   FROM     college_details cd
                  )
SELECT   c.college_name
     CURSOR ( SELECT    o.department
              FROM      (SELECT tc.department
                              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tc.college_id) rnum
                         FROM   temp_college tc
                         WHERE  tc.college_id  = c.college_id
                        ) o
             WHERE     o.rnum BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
            )
FROM     coll_details c
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is include the `college_id` in the innermost sub-query then filter on the CURSOR statement:

```
SELECT   c.college_name
    , CURSOR ( select department from (
                  SELECT   tc.college_id 
                           , tc.department
                           , row_number() over (partition by tc.college_id 
                                                     order by tc.department_id) rn
              FROM  temp_college tc
                  ) tc
                  where tc.college_id  = c.college_id 
                  and rn <= 3
            ) coll_depts
FROM college_details  c
/
```

Demo (inline cursor output is *ugly*).

```
COLLEGE_NAME     COLL_DEPTS
---------------- --------------------
FOX COLLEGE      CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

DEPARTMENT
--------------------
PHYSICS
LATIN

BEETLE COLLEGE   CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

DEPARTMENT
--------------------
ETYMOLOGY
EARTH SCIENCE

KNOX INSTITUTE   CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

DEPARTMENT
--------------------
ASTROPHYSICS
COMPUTER SCIENCE


SQL>
```

NB: the demo uses pagination of `2` because of the sample data.

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look.. i am using pagination concept here so i have to use that inner cursor

Comment: For future reference, please post a complete set of requirements. Posting incomplete or half-baked question just wastes peoples' time. And that's no way to treat those you are asking to help you.